# Flutter Steamprovider doesnt update listeners

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, stream, provider

I am using "Just Audio" package to play audio.
The Package does provide a PlayerState stream.
I am creating a Streamprovider:

> StreamProvider.value(
> value: AudioPlayer().playerStateStream,
> ),

[ToolTip for playerStateStream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAicy.png)

and I am subscribing to it like this:

> var radioPlayerState = Provider.of(context);

However nothing happens to my play button when I start the audio

**Update:**
Making AudioPlayer() global and always using the instance for all actions and references **worked.
Is there a better solution?**

Comment: You have given the type of provider you listening in your case what is the class of  `AudioPlayer().playerStateStream` ex: String or Int or Some object the only provider will listen to the changes

Answer (score 0):

So making AudioPlayer global instead of using AudioPlayer() everytime I need a function from the AudioPlayer solved the problem.